# Meteor: Load only .html from specific sub-directory into page

Tags: meteor

I'm attempting to create a simple project for rapid prototyping using Meteor, Meteor Router, and Bootstrap.

**Here's the directory Structure**

```
meteor-prototypes/
|
|--- .meteor/
|--- prototypes/
|    |
|    |--- example/
|         |
|         |--- example.coffee
|         |--- example.css
|         |--- example-index.html
|         |--- example-more.html
|
|--- prototypes.coffee
|--- index.html
|--- smart.json
|--- smart.lock
```

The `example` folder represents a single prototype, reachable at (for example) `http://localhost:3000/prototypes/example/`. Ideally, you would be able to add another prototype to the project simply by duplicating `example/` with a new name (e.g. new-example) and visiting `http://localhost:3000/prototypes/new-example/`.

The problem with this is that Meteor, by default, searches the entire project directory for HTML files and loads them all. What I need to do is check which prototype we're viewing based on the URL (through Meteor Router) and load only the .html files in that folder (e.g. `example/`).

**Is there a way to tell Meteor to load only .html files in a specific subdirectory? Or another way to accomplish this?**

**For those curious, or in case it helps, here are what each of the files mentioned in the directory structure above contain:**

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <title>desktime-prototypes</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{ renderPage }}
</body>

<template name="home">
    <h1>We have the following prototypes available:</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/example/">Example</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**prototypes.coffee**

```
if (Meteor.isClient)

  Meteor.Router.add
    '': 'home'

    '/:prototype': (params) ->
      return params

    '/:prototype/:page': (params) ->
      return params[1]

if (Meteor.isServer)
  Meteor.startup ->
    # code to run on server at startup
```

**/prototypes/example.coffee**

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Template.example.greeting = ->
    return "Welcome to prototypes."

  Template.example.rendered = ->
    # This function will fire when this specific template gets rendered,
    # Great place to fire jQuery plugins, or anything else that needs
    # to happen when the DOM is ready.

  Template.example.events
    'click input' : ->
      # template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      alert 'Button clicked!'
```

**prototypes/example/example-index.html**

```
<template name="example">
    <h1>Welcome to the example prototype!</h1>

    {{> example-more }}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Great question...two things:

**(1)**  `meteor-router` currently lacks the server side rendering you need ([though it's close](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#server-side-routing)).

**(2)**  HTML file names are *completely irrelevant* to the routing system. The folders in which they live matter insofar as the order they're loaded, but the names do not match to routes the way you expect.

To achieve what you're looking for you can (1) use links in the app for routing but don't change the URL in the address bar and expect that to work yet, and (2) change the template names of the various html files in your /prototypes folder to match the prototype you're wanting to demo. Below is an example:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>All Prototypes</h1>
    {{>proto}}
    <div>
        {{renderPage}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="landing">
    LANDING
</template>

<template name="proto">
   {{#each items}}
        <a href="/prototypes/{{id}}">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Meteor.Router.to("/landing");
    });
    Meteor.Router.add({
        '/landing': 'landing',
        '/prototypes/:page': function (proto) {
            return proto;
        }
    });
    Template.proto.items = function () {
        return [{ name: "Prototype 1", id: "prototype1" }, { name: "Prototype 2", id: "prototype2" }];
    };
}
```

Prototype 1 HTML:

```
<template name="prototype1">
    <h1>Prototype 1</h1>
</template>
```

Prototype 2 HTML:

```
<template name="prototype2">
    <h1>Prototype 2</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: Yep, this makes sense. I'm confused about why I shouldn't expect the URL to map to routing? As you've described it, wouldn't http://localhost:3000/prototypes/prototype1/ correctly map to that prototype template?

Comment: @cmal: it would if meteor-router [had sophisticated enough server side rendering](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#server-side-routing); i.e., the spark engine ran on the server. I know that a routing package is in their [official roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm).

Comment: When you run this app and click the Prototype1 link from within the app itself, then YES that is the URL you will see. But you cannot type that into the address bar and expect to see the same thing until server side rendering is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want multiple prototypes inside one Meteor project? Do they share code? If not, why not just use one Meteor project per prototype? And then what you could do is create a command line util yourself that does something like

```
meteor_proto example1
meteor_proto example2
```

which creates Meteor projects but just pre-populates them with the files you want (you could create your ideal prototyping project and put it somewhere, then just have your command line copy the contents of that folder over while after doing a `meteor create` command or something).

This would be a nice feature for Meteor to have by default, actually.

Comment: Rahul: Thanks for the comment, and I did consider having one project per prototype as you're describing. There are two major reasons I did not: 1) DRY, I don't want to need to maintain a dozen projects 2) The prototypes will often be part of the same app design process and it would be nice if they can communicate/link with eachother when needed.

Comment: Also, I have thought for a long time that Meteor needs a convenient way of creating new projects from templates (e.g. meteor create my-project -t my-template)